# Getting Sementation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, uart

I get string data from UART and convert it to hex. After converting to hex , I have two unique delimiters "06" and "07". I want to get the data between these two delimiters. I tried to build the code below based on what i said. But after receiving 6-7 outputs, I get segmentation fault error.

```
 std::string sub_between(std::string start,std::string stop,std::string input)
    {
       auto start_index = input.find(start);
       if (start_index != std::string::npos) 
       {
          auto stop_index = input.find(stop,start_index+start.size());
          if (stop_index != std::string::npos)
          {
            return {input.begin() + start_index+start.size(), input.begin() + stop_index};
          }
       }
        //  return empty string
        return {};
    }

    int main(int argc, char ** argv) 

{
  int uart0_filestream = -1;
  int uart2_filestream = -1;
  unsigned char rx_buffer[1024];
  memset(&rx_buffer[0], 0, 1023);

  unsigned char tx_buffer[1024];
  memset(&tx_buffer[0], 0, 1023);

  std::stringstream ss;


  if(uart0_filestream == -1)
  {
    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    //uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_NOCTTY );
    
    if(uart0_filestream == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "UARTListener::Start Unable to open UART" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      struct termios options;
      tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
      options.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;   //<Set baud rate
      options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
      options.c_oflag = 0;
      options.c_lflag = 0;
      //options.c_line = '\n';
      //options.c_cc[VEOL] = 0; 
      tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
      tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
    }
  }

    while(true)
    {
      memset(&rx_buffer[0], 0, 1024);
      int rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*) rx_buffer, 1023);
      if(rx_length > 0)
      {
        rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
        //std::string txt = std::string((char*) rx_buffer);

        for (int i = 0; i < rx_length ; i++)
        {
           ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)<< std::hex << (int)rx_buffer[i];
           //ss << std::hex << (int)rx_buffer[i];
        }
        std::string startDEL = "06";
        std::string stopDEL =  "07";

        std::string concat = std::accumulate(std::begin(ss.str()),std::end(ss.str()),std::string(""));
        std::cout << "Pulled Data : " << ss.str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "String : " << sub_between(startDEL,stopDEL,concat) << std::endl;

      //std::cout << txt << std::endl;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

--OUTPUT--

```
    Pulled Data : 42
    String : 
    Pulled Data : 426561636f6e
    String : 
    Pulled Data : 426561636f6e283229
    String : 
    Pulled Data : 426561636f6e28322920466f756e
    String : 
    Pulled Data : 426561636f6e28322920466f756e645b355d
    String : 
    Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to learn where in your code it happens? When the crash happens, what are the values of all involved variables?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, `stringstream::str()` returns string by value, so you have dangling references `std::accumulate(std::begin(ss.str()),std::end(ss.str())` when iterating over strings.

Comment: By the way, do you want to continue and append to the string stream `ss` all through the reading loop? That seems wrong to me. Perhaps you should have defined `ss` in the closest scope, right before the `for` loop.

Comment: Your `accumulate` looks like a very roundabout and inefficient way of copying `ss.str()`. What is the point of it?

Comment: when you post code written by someone else you better give proper attribution. Don't get me wrong, I am not complaining because it is from my answer, that just made it easier to spot, but in general I am rather picky about that. It is not only about giving credits to whom credits due, but also for useful context. For example one might complain that you pass the strings by value, but actually that isnt your mistake but mine (somehow i forgot to fix it in the answer)

Comment: also useful context, because it would make clear why there is a `std::accumulate` in your code. Its an artifact of a previous version, you don't need it here.